# What does it mean by "with a note" in the following setence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading about **floating point numbers** in a programming language book and faced with the following sentence :

> For example, 0.1 is stored as 1, **with a note** to shift the decimal
> point one place  to the left. 12.75 is stored as 1275, **with a note** to
> shift the decimal point two places to the left.

Can anybody explain to me that what "**with a note**" means?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you asking what the word "note" means in this context? If so, please check a dictionary and see if any of the meanings there fit this context. Or are you asking what "a note" means in the context of a book about programming? If so, please give us more context, like what type of book it is, what the surrounding context is, and so on.

Comment: It is a nontechnical way of saying there is an accompanying piece of stored information (how much the decimal point should be shifted).

Comment: Not part of your question, but I suggest "programming language book", rather than "language programming book".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @nschneid said in a comment, it is a non-technical way of conveying how the actual number is stored. If you blur your eyes enough, "with a note" is a *metaphor* for a physical **[note](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/note#Noun)**<sup>1</sup> that tells you how to interpret the information.

The metaphor says this:

> Someone wanted to express the number `12.75` in a way that you can understand. They wrote the sequence of digits `00000001275` on a piece of paper. They also wrote the words "*The decimal place goes after the third-rightmost digit*" on another piece of paper. They gave both pieces of paper to you, so you know to interpret the information as the number `12.75`.

In the metaphor, the second piece of information telling you where to put the decimal place is the **note**.

This is the whole idea behind "floating-point" notation: the decimal point *floats* (moves) back and forth between the digits. This means the system can express both very large and very small numbers without changing how many bits are used.

The actual implementation of this idea will be explained in your textbook.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Wiktionary: *A written or printed communication or commitment.*</sup>

Comment: So can I say that the term 'note' says to me what I have to do?

Comment: Sort of. "Note" is more informational; something telling you what you *have* to do would be an "instruction." In this context "instruction" would work just as well though—you *have* to put the decimal point in the right place, or you will not be using the correct number.

Comment: Thank you. Excuse me, in your explanation above, you said: ` In this context "instruction" would work just as well though—you have to put..`, but why did you use ** as well though—you have to** in this way? I mean why did you write "—" between "though" and "you "?

Comment: And is this example true? **I've put my shoes on the desk, with a not I shouldn't put them there**. I mean, although I knew I shouldn't put them on the desk, I did it!

Comment: For the first question look up "em dash." For the second... whether that's a "true" example depends on whether you did it or not! It does seem a strange thing to do.

Comment: Can you explain it in more details please ? (: